# How to add content to "Add New Post" page in Wordpress

Tags: tinymce, wordpress-theming, wordpress

What should I do if I want to add some HTML to "Add New Post" page in Wordpress (/wp-admin/post-new.php), for example above the text editor?

Comment: what did you try ? any code ?

Comment: I am trying to insert a button which would reveal a set of tools, similar to WPBakery Visual Composer ([link](http://demo.wpbakery.com/vc/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page)).

Comment: Do you want a new metabox or a new button (like bold)?

Comment: I want a new button, but outside TinyMCE, not like bold or any other TinyMCE feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the hook [`edit_form_after_title`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=edit_form_after_title) to put content in that position.

Comment: Yes, thanks, actually I was wandering if there is native hook in Wordpress for this.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to dig the TinyMCE which is the embedded editor in wordpress.

Here is the documentation which tells you how to add buttons, create plugin etc. : http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that way, though the place where I want to add content and where authors of Visual Composer added their content doesn't really seem to be part of TinyMCE, it is just above it. But maybe there is no other way.

Comment: What the final goal of the integration of the button? I mean what will the button do?

Comment: Final goal is to make functionality similar to WPBakery Visual Composer (hide / show set of layout handling tools).